# How to show a Time Series chart by Date + Hour in Data Studio - only showing up as 12AM

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, timeserieschart

I'm trying to have a time series chart show the number of sessions by date and hour for the last 30 days in Data Studio. When I set my Dimension to "Date", and select the "Date Hour" Type, it just gives me the 30 days, but rather than breaking it down by the hour, it sums up the entire day's sessions to all being at 12AM. I have also tried going into "Manage added data sources" and duplicating my Date dimension to be "Date Time" (I'm pulling data from Google Analytics). Does anyone know how to make my time series chart show the number of sessions by hour for each date?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Analytics has several separate dimensions for date and hour od the day so you can't report using just a single `Date` dimension. `Date` doesn't support hourly granularity.
Check [Dimensions and Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) for a relevant hour dimension, like `Hour` that can be used in combination with `Date` or `Hour of Day`